# Using < and > characters in Javadoc

Tags: java, special-characters, javadoc

I have been writing up Javadoc comments and have run into a problem. If I try to describe a list in the form:

List < String > (Assume no spaces)

the <> characters are recognized and hide the entire  portion of the comment within the Javadoc. I have looked at the documentation one the oracle website here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format without any luck.

How should I format my comments such that the < String > is visible? is there a solution similar to \" when using quotation marks?

Comment: Try putting it in `{@code ...}`

Comment: I prefer this method to &gt; and &lt; as it is slightly more readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

< and > are tag indicators in HTML, like <p>. That's why they don't show up. To fix, use &gt; and &lt;

Comment: if you use `&lt;` for `<` you can use `>` as normal because you haven't opened a HTML tag. But that looks kind of strange.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't... It's more correct to use the uni code symbol. Kind of the equivalent of storing a phone number as a string, because you should never be doing maths with it. Chances are you'd never run into issues with &lt; and >, but with &lt; and &gt; you will never run into issues